# Listing of manufacturer's clock / alarm package and class name, Please add

Tags: android, class, package, clock

THis is not really a question, Sorry. I just wanted help on getting the package and class names of alarm and clocks of different android makers' clock and alarm.

I have a listing here of HTC, Samsung, and stock android class names.
But you can guess the package names.

```
// HTC
"com.htc.android.worldclock.TimerAlert",//
"com.htc.android.worldclock.AlarmAlert",//

// Samsung
"com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage",//
"com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.alarm.AlarmAlert",//

// Motorola
"com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmAlert",//
"com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock",//
"com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmTimerAlert",

// Stock Android Clock
"com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock",// 1.5 / 1.6
"com.android.deskclock.DeskClock",//
```

If you have an LG, Sony, or any other android maker out there, please
add to this list. i beg you.

Comment: I used "com.htc.android.worldclock.AlarmAlert" and I got a crash report on Google Play: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

Comment: Same here with "com.android.deskclock/.DeskClock"

Answer (score 14):

Here some munifactures and actions, plus thirdparty actions (thirdparty alarm apps)

```
// Stock alarms
// Nexus (?)
"com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT";
"com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS";
"com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE";
"com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE";
// stock Android (?)
"com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";
// Stock alarm Manufactures
// Samsung
"com.samsung.sec.android.clockpackage.alarm.ALARM_ALERT";
// HTC
"com.htc.android.worldclock.ALARM_ALERT";
// Sony
"com.sonyericsson.alarm.ALARM_ALERT";
// ZTE
"zte.com.cn.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";
// Motorola
"com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";

// Thirdparty Alarms
// Gentle Alarm
"com.mobitobi.android.gentlealarm.ALARM_INFO";
// Sleep As Android
"com.urbandroid.sleep.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";
// Alarmdroid (1.13.2)
"com.splunchy.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";
```

This are broadcast actions, which you can receive with a receiver.

Edit:
I've found the alarm action for the  LG phones:

```
com.lge.alarm.alarmclocknew
```

Comment: How can I get those actions from another apps? I have installed them in the emulator and I see the logcat but I am not able to see where the action is at to copy it. Any help?

Comment: I got some from log cat reading. Sometimes the app offers the Action as logcat output, some times the ActivityManager talks to you about the action.

Its a little bit tricky, but the most Android stock alarms provide the action directly to the logcat output.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for sharing the information!

Sony Ericsson XPERIA X10 Mini Pro, Android 2.1:
Package name: 'com.sonyericsson.alarm',
Activity name: 'com.sonyericsson.alarm.Alarm'

Samsung Galaxy S Vibrant, Android 2.2:
Package name: 'com.sec.android.app.clockpackage',
Activity name: 'com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage'

This information based on AVD:

Stock Clock, Android 2.1:
Package name: 'com.android.alarmclock',
Activity name: 'com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock'

Stock Clock, Android 2.2:
Package name: 'com.android.alarmclock',
Activity name: 'com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock'

Stock Clock, Android 2.3 (2.3.1):
Package name: 'com.android.deskclock',
Activity name: 'com.android.deskclock.DeskClock'

Stock Clock, Android 2.3.3:
Package name: 'com.android.deskclock',
Activity name: 'com.android.deskclock.DeskClock'

Answer (score 7):

```
{"HTC Alarm Clock", "com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl" },
{"Standar Alarm Clock", "com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"},
{"Froyo Nexus Alarm Clock", "com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock"},
{"Moto Blur Alarm Clock", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock",  "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock"}
```

Answer (score 5):

// HTC One

"com.htc.android.ALARM_ALERT";

Answer (score 5):

Small addition to previous answers (I think no one mentioned LG):

```
{"LG Alarm Clock", "com.lge.clock", "com.lge.clock.AlarmClockActivity"} // newer devices e.g. LG G3
{"LG Alarm Clock", "com.lge.clock", "com.lge.clock.DefaultAlarmClockActivity"} // older devices e.g. LG-E610
```

It would be really cool to have this for Sony or other manufacturers too. It's easy to find out, only grep your logcat when starting Alarm Clock app like this:

```
adb logcat *:v | grep "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
```

and the output looks like:

```
I/ActivityManager(  466): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.lge.clock/.DefaultAlarmClockActivity u=0} from pid 735
```

EDIT:
For Sony it should be like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167545/237232):

```
{"Sony Ericsson Xperia Z", "com.sonyericsson.organizer", "com.sonyericsson.organizer.Organizer_WorldClock" }
```

Answer (score 0):

OnePlus
"com.oneplus.deskclock"