# where is alarm clock functionality in android?

Tags: android

I am writing a reminder app and obviously it needs alarm clock functionality. Features like "repeat on sun, mon, fri", play recorded audio as alarm, play text as briefing would be nice to have. Instead of reinventing the wheel, it would be convenient to have my app call the activity that provides this functionality.

If I wanted to set a basic alarm, I would simply pass in the millisec to set() in AlarmManager in the android API. For more complex functionality as described above, it is not available as part of the API. I cannot run or test against an imaginary 3rd party provider.

However, AlarmClock in android does have these features but unfortunately is simply an empty class with constants
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html

DeskClock source code is here
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master/src/com/android/deskclock/
but it is not in the API to call into.

Also, importing as an android project into Eclipse gives over 100 compile errors

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
TimePickerDialog cannot be resolved AlarmUtils.java /DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock    line 61 Java Problem
The method onPageSelected(int) of type DeskClock.TabsAdapter must override or implement a supertype method  DeskClock.java  /DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock    line 409    Java Problem
The method showTimeEditDialog(FragmentManager, null, AlarmClockFragment, boolean) is undefined for the type AlarmUtils  AlarmClockFragment.java /DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock    line 1677   Java Problem
The method showTimeEditDialog(FragmentManager, Alarm, AlarmClockFragment, boolean) is undefined for the type AlarmUtils AlarmClockFragment.java /DeskClock/src/com/android/deskclock    line 1055   Java Problem
```

Can one reuse existing alarm clock functionality in android?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my impression is that there's normally no "sharable" functionality for this in Android itself.  You could see if there might be some API for adding things to the Google Calendar on a device which supports that.  Or you are free to write your own Alarm Clock app with an API for exchanging alarm information with other apps.

Comment: Your operations are not that complex. You can schedule the alarm with AlarmManager based on whatever conditions you'd like, just a simple math needs to be employed. Since your question has substantially changed after my answer was posted, I'll request for my answer to be removed

Comment: And no, there isn't a system app that will calculate your alarm times, allow the user to choose an alarm sound and then return the info so you can just schedule the alarm with the AlarmManager. Even if this did exist, you'll still have to store and process the events by yourself

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a system app that will show the user a time chooser, calculate your alarm times, allow the user to choose an alarm sound and then return the info so you can just schedule the alarm with the AlarmManager.

Even if this did exist, you'll still have to store and process the events by yourself.

Comment: that is not what I am asking. I do know one can send out an implicit intent to possible providers. I want to know which specific implementaton - if this were in the API, I could simply test against it.

Comment: Test what exactly? From the following block of text I understood that you need to set an alarm in a third-party app "my app call the activity that provides this functionality"

Comment: If I wanted to set a basic alarm, I would simply pass in the millisec to set() in AlarmManager in the android API. For more complex functionality as described above, it is not available as part of the API. I cannot run or test against an imaginary 3rd party provider.

Comment: I have my UI and so do not need an alarm clock UI. I wanted to be able to pass in the information in the AlarmClock class to schedule an alarm.

Comment: You can do that, I wrote an example for that in my previous answer