# Android - accessing the android stock timer

Tags: android, timer

So here's my problem, I've got a recipe app in which I want the user to be able to hit a button and then be sent to the stock android countdown app.

I can create my own timer but I think that it would be nicer to use the  one that comes with the device (I wouldn't be able to make it as nice).

As far as I can tell every android device comes with one, yet I am not sure how to access them (all I want to do is launch them). Does anyone know of a specific package name or the best way to access the Time?

**EDIT:**

I've looked around quite a bit without success, what I'm looking to do is something like this : 
`PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();`

`Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package.Timer");`
`startActivity(i);`

Or anything else that may work.

Comment: What API level does your app need ?

Comment: well im developing it to work on 8 and up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ginger bread that is on API level 10 does not have a default GUI timer / stopwatch. I'm not sure about the consistent availability of a timer on other versions, but I'm sure that API levels above 8 do not consistently ship with timers (at the GUI level). If I were you I'd rather build my own timer and display it to the user.

Comment: yes im afraid you are right, practicaly none of the versions have the same package name anyway. thanks for you help. This may be helpful to anyone else --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115649/listing-of-manufacturers-clock-alarm-package-and-class-name-please-add