# Android alarmclock broadcast/detection

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to do something when the alarmclock fires. Show a toast or set a new alarm for example. I was looking for something to detect when the a alarmclock fires. First I was searching for a broadcast action, but I could not find one. My bad maybe?

Is there any other way do something when the alarmclock fires and how will this work with a custom alarmclock?

Comment: Please see my answer here: [Detect default alarm clock application alarms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553196/detect-default-alarm-clock-application-alarms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but right now it's not possible to know when an AlarmClock fires, and could happen that some user could use a 3rd application which could make it more hard to communicate with every possible application since don't exists a standard-way (or i don't know if exists, i can't find after research).

The class `AlarmClock` don't provide a way to manage it (Alarm Clocks will use AlarmManager to make this.) just a way to ask to the clock application to set an alarm.

Personally if you really need to do something like this you could work directly with the [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class (which gives you more freedom on what you want to do, when do it etc.)

Maybe if you force your users to use a specific clock application (which provides to you a way to know it) you can do something. But you will end up with lose users.

Comment: It's a privacy feature that apps can't query the AlarmManager.  If it's a custom alarm clock have a go at scheduling a pending intent with the AlarmManager to call your app.