# Don't work intent action in received

Tags: java, android, android-intent, huawei-mobile-services

I have some problem with intent action in broadcast receiver, when alarm is ringing in log action ALARM_ALERT output, but when i off alarm on my phone Huawei Honor 5A, i don't see action in log ALARM_DONE.
Notice: I test this code on Genymotion on Android, this work fine, but on my phone install MUI, maybe it's problem?

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "LockScreen/BootReceiver";
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.e(TAG,"onReceive  " + action);
    //If the screen was just turned on or it just booted up, start your Lock Activity
    if (action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT") ||
            action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE"))
    {
        UserHolder.setRingState(true);
    }
    if(action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS") ||
            action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE")) {
        UserHolder.setRingState(false);
    }

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
                || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
                || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
                //LockScreenService.service.stopForeground(true);
                UserHolder.saveScreenOff(context);
            }
            Parameters parameters = Parameters.getFromDB();
            if (!UserHolder.isAlarm() &&!UserHolder.callIsRunning()
                    && UserHolder.isLogin() && parameters.getUserWidgetOnoff() == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //i.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);
                context.startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Logger.info("ignore onReceive  " + action);
            }

    }
```

Intent filter:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        filter.addAction("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT");
        filter.addAction("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE");
        filter.addAction("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS");
        filter.addAction("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE");
```

Manifest:

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT" />
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE" />
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS" />
            <action android:name="com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: look for your logcat panel, see if you have any filtering and see if you have chosen the device and not the genymotion virtual device, show your intent-filter as well in your manifest

Comment: I performed the tests separately, and check this

Comment: @Roljhon i write initent filter and manifest, can check this?

Comment: alright, I think that should, perhaps the huawei is not using a default clock app, so that means they're using different actions, which you should find exactly. Maybe this can help you with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957548/android-open-activity-when-alarm-clock-is-done-or-dismmised

Comment: @Roljhon i check this through LogCat and when i dismiss or done alarm on phone, nothing happen intent action in log, but when alarm is ringing i see ALARM_ALERT. Notice: it's without any filters in LogCat, i check all logs

Comment: dude, I've already provided the possible reason above :) and that is actually true I believed. Can't provide an exact solution since it depends on the phone if it's using a stock alarm actions or not

Comment: @Roljhon so how find/catch this action?